# Chrome / Firefox extension to make Single Click open folder/file in new Google Drive

Tags: chrome, firefox, google-drive

New Google Drive requires double-click to open folder/file.

Could you recommend Chrome/Firefox extensions to enable me to use single click for those operations?
(Or extension that can I configure or easily script to achieve given effect?)